# Volley returns always with "Failed"

Tags: android, android-studio, android-volley

I'm using Volley to call api but it always returns "Failed" String in the onResponse method.
I checked the request object and response object and they are the same in postman, post man returns result but volley return "Failed".

Here's the call in fragment 
[image]

And the call using volley

[image]

Comment: Can you show us the code of that call..?

Comment: @PraveenSP  i'll update my question

Comment: have you decleared internet permissions in manifest.?? also if you are using android 9 or above make sure you have declread  "android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"" in manifest in application tag

Comment: @AkashBisht no use